# Python adding to dictionary only by key

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say i have a city (value) and people (key).
1 city can have many people.

(For example.):
Code:

```
cities = {'Berlin':{'Dan', 'john'},'Tokyo':{'John'}}
city_dict = {}
people = {}
for city in cities:
   ?
```

i want to construct a dictionary in python which insert only if a match between keys occurring.

(For example the desired result.):

```
{'dan' : {'dan':'berlin','dan':'colorado'},'john' : {'john':'berlin','john':'Tokyo'}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about `{'dan' : {'berlin', 'colorado'},'john' : {'berlin', 'Tokyo'}}` ? Why do you need the names again and again anyway?

Answer (score 3):

The desired result can't be achieved as dictionaries, by definition, can't contain duplicated keys.

You can, however, do the following (which is somehow close to the output you wanted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

cities = {'Berlin': {'Dan', 'John'}, 'Tokyo': {'John'}}
output = defaultdict(set)

for city, names in cities.items():
    for name in names:
        output[name].add(city)
print(output)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'Dan': {'Berlin'}, 'John': {'Berlin', 'Tokyo'}})
```

Answer (score 2):

Other option, without dependencies and returning list of cities:

```
cities = {'Berlin':{'Dan', 'John'},'Tokyo':{'John', 'Paul'}, 'Liverpool':{'John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo'}, 'Colorado':{'Ringo'} }

res = {}
for k, v in cities.items():
  for e in v:
    res.setdefault(e,[]).append(k)

print(res)
#=> {'Dan': ['Berlin'], 'John': ['Berlin', 'Tokyo', 'Liverpool'], 'Paul': ['Tokyo', 'Liverpool'], 'Ringo': ['Liverpool', 'Colorado'], 'George': ['Liverpool']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a dictionary with duplicate keys like @DeepSpace indicated, so for your problem I can suggest you the following alternative.
Use a dictionary with people's name for keys and for value the cities. And so when you want when combine the two for creating a list tuples or so on.

```
people = {"Dan": ["Berlin","San Francisco"], "Mario": ["Rome"]}

for name, locations in people:
  #combine name with single city if needed
  for city in locations:
    tuple_tmp = (name,city)
    #next store it, print it,...
```

This approach cons are:

- You need to process the values
- If you have city and and want to retrieve all names in this one is very slow operation.
  You can maintain another structure with the inverted relation, but it's memory consuming.